# Does an Upsert violate the Single Responsibility Principle?

Tags: sql, sql-server, oop, design-patterns, stored-procedures

I like to use Upsert stored procedures that update records if they exist or insert them if they don't. Without them, I would need to first find out if the record exists, and then have two separate stored procedures that I would call based on the result.

I never really thought about the issue before today when I was creating a stored procedure called UpdateOrDeleteRow. As soon as I found myself including "Or" in the name, my SRP spider sense kicked in, and I realized that the upserts are basically the same thing.

Is this a violation of SRP? If so, is it acceptable? If not, what should I do?

I realize that the SRP is an OOP principle, and T-SQL is not an OOP language, but the basis for the principle seems like it should apply here as well.

Comment: What is the Single Responsibility Principle?

Comment: Basically that every class should do one thing only.

Comment: I agree with @HeadOfCatering in that every class should do one thing, but what is "one thing"? Every class should have a single responsibility where a responsibility is defined as "a reason to change."  Therefore a class should only have one reason to change in order to conform to the [single responsibility principle](http://www.oodesign.com/single-responsibility-principle.html).

Comment: I agree with you, Jake. I'm absolutely not advocating blind adherence to a principle. However, I do like to examine what I'm doing to make sure that when I'm breaking a "rule", I'm doing so for the right reason.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Personally I don't believe that this principle applies completely in SQL Server. Stored procedures don't always perform just one action (and I think the notion that a stored procedure is equivalent to a class is flawed). I don't think it makes sense to split every single statement in a stored procedure into its own stored procedure. You can get absolutely ridiculous with this.

There is a balance of course, as you can be ridiculous the other way. You don't want a stored procedure with 18 different ways to specify parameters so that it can do 540 different things based on the combinations.

For an UPSERT I would still suggest that a single stored procedure is fine for this. If you want to feel better about it serving a single purpose, change your update/insert into a single `MERGE`. :-)  That said, and in all seriousness, [be very careful with `MERGE`](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3074/use-caution-with-sql-servers-merge-statement/?utm_source=AaronBertrand).

Comment: Could you come up with some definition when it's time to split the stored procedures (you brought some boundary cases which illustrate why it's not good to be extreme, but I'm still missing some definition for all that gray area in between)?

Comment: @BornToCode you want me to define your gray area?

Comment: I'm particulary trying to find some guideline about things like unions, how to know when it's better to write one sproc with union vs. two separate sprocs?

Answer (score 5):

There is another principle, which I like even more, than SRP - [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself). So, if you call this sequence in one place, you can think about single responsibility. But when you repeating same sequence of actions several times, DRY makes me to remove duplication.

BTW Just come to my mind, that you can avoid `OR` in procedure/method name. `UpdateOrInsert` operation has very good name `Save`. I think it does not breaks SRP.

Comment: I think you've just created the Rock Paper Scissors Principle: when SRP and DRY conflict, DRY wins.

Comment: @HeadofCatering :) We should find something, that better than DRY, but worse than SRP

Answer (score 2):

I would disagree that the principal should apply in this case as it makes for some redundant code in your codebehind.

First lets examine what your UPSERT does,  It checks if data exists then based on that it executes an INSERT or an UPDATE.

In codebehind to do this you have to make 2 calls to your database, depending on how your application is structured this could also mean opening and closing two connections.

So you have 3 methods in codebehind (one to execute each proc) then a method to call each of those methods and do the logic to decide if you need to insert or update.

You also have 3 seperate stored procedures in your database to do each of the actions.

This to me seems like badly structured code since you would be passing the same parameters to your insert / update procedures as you would to your upsert, it therefore makes sense to do this all in one place.

By using an UPSERT you have 1 stored procedure and only need the one connection, with one method to be called from codebehind. I think that this makes for much better, cleaner code.

Answer (score 1):

If you already have procs that do the Update or Delete operations independently, hopefully with logging for auditing purposes, you could have your upsert proc call those individually.  That way only those procs are doing the work which should help keep things manageable, even if they're being called from multiple locations.

Answer (score 1):

The single responsibility principle says that an object should only have one reason to change.  The only reason that an Upsert stored procedure should change is if the table structure changes.  Thus, I think you are okay in creating upsert stored procedures.